# No Push Notification Capability in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I don't know why, but the option Push Notifications of Capabilities in Xcode is not displayed. Why?

I follow the developer guides, creating cers, enabling push in provisiong profiles, etc.

I had refreshed the account in Xcode preferences. What I am doing wrong?

[image: xcode]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426422/how-to-update-provisioning-profile-for-push-notification-ios

Answer (score 25):

You need a apple account not free,Please see the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

I was using the free developer's account and decided to upgrade to a paid 99 USD account. Because I was using free, the advanced capabilities did not display until I removed my account by clicking on the  '-' and clicked on the '+' to re-add my account. Then all the capabilities appeared.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Try checking all the following.

- Make sure Push notifications is turned on under developer.apple.com.
- If yes, then make sure you are running the same provisioning profile and certificate.
- Also in Xcode, under Project -> General -> Select the qualifying team.

This should work.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem because my Apple Developer membership was expired. Renew it and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

This setting does not exist anymore. Just make sure that your App ID includes Push Notifications in the [dev center](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action).
Then, register for push notifications with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Has  Push Notifications of Capabilities in Xcode7