# Push Notificaion capability

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing mobile app by using nativescript with angular. For earlier version of the app, we didn't include Push Notification when we published the app on both stores. Now, we included Push Notification in the app. It is OK when I published the app on Google Play Store. But when I built the app to upload on the Apple Store, I got the following error.

[image]
If you already this problem and solved, please let me know how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate Push Notification capabilities from xcode for your provisioning profile.

Check this question[Xcode Push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979218/no-push-notification-capability-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developer.apple.com/ and edit your App Id settings.

Should be under `App Ids` inside `Identifiers` in left hand side. and then select your app id's `Setup and configure services for this App ID.` Enabled the **Push Notifications**.

You need to regenrate the provison profile for this is.