# wonderpush notification cordova plugin build error

Tags: ios, cordova, provisioning-profile, ipa, wonderpush

the plugin wonderpush-corodva-sdk
can't export and ipa

```
[19:41:08] Running command: xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath Joy Hope Messenger.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist /private/tmp/download/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist -exportPath /private/tmp/download/platforms/ios/build/device -allowProvisioningUpdates
[19:41:09] 2022-03-09 19:41:09.010 xcodebuild[2250:13261] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path "/var/folders/q3/dxjx12d13p7bvtn3t8_9w6bm0000gp/T/Joy Hope Messenger_2022-03-09_19-41-09.010.xcdistributionlogs".
[19:41:10] ** EXPORT FAILED **
```

with the following error

```
[19:41:10] error: exportArchive: "Joy Hope Messenger.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.
[19:41:10] Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""Joy Hope Messenger.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription="Joy Hope Messenger.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}
[19:41:10] error: exportArchive: "WonderPushNotificationServiceExtension.appex" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.
[19:41:10] Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""WonderPushNotificationServiceExtension.appex" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription="WonderPushNotificationServiceExtension.appex" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}
```

can anyone guest what's wrong? thx

Answer (score 0):

It says it in your log

```
 requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature
```

You did not setup push notifications properly in Apple Dev. There is [a thread about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426422/how-to-update-provisioning-profile-for-push-notification-ios) that can help you out.

Comment: I have setup two provisioning profile.