# Xamarin Forms iOS : aps-environment element not found in provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, testflight

I have created a Xamarin Forms solution in Visual Studio 2022.  I am testing the iOS mobile app using Apple's Test Flight.  In order to enable push notifications, I have added the "aps-environment = production" element to the Entitlements.plist file.  After having created my App ID, certificate, and provisioning profile, I am able to bundle and create the ipa file.

After moving my ipa file to my Mac in the Cloud, I am able to use the Transporter app to verify and post the ipa file to Test Flight.  However during the verification step, I get the error saying -

Asset validation failed (90163)

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'aps-environment' in 'Payload/[blah]/[blah]'. (ID: bec9f266-107e-4d85-82c3-0eaf1a539644)

I have searched through the Apple docs and cannot find any way to add the "aps-environment" element to provisioning profile.

Comment: The message is a bit misleading. FIRST create a CERTIFICATE that includes push notifications. THEN download a new provisioning profile, based on that certificate. [How to update provisioning profile for Push Notification - IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426422/how-to-update-provisioning-profile-for-push-notification-ios). That answer doesn't explain in detail; search for apple docs for creating certificate. Then whatever you did to get provisioning profile before, do that again, using that certificate.

Answer (score 0):

As ToolmakerSteve said that:

> The message is a bit misleading. FIRST create a CERTIFICATE that includes push notifications. THEN download a new provisioning profile, based on that certificate. [How to update provisioning profile for Push Notification - IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426422/how-to-update-provisioning-profile-for-push-notification-ios). That answer doesn't explain in detail; search for apple docs for creating certificate. Then whatever you did to get provisioning profile before, do that again, using that certificate.